# Suggestions for "best" questions

Tags: discussion

I'm presenting at our local OWASP branch tonight, trying to get more people on the site.

Any suggestions for the "best" questions, that would really show off the benefit of the site?
Nothing trite or easily googlable... but questions (or answers!) that would make an experienced security consultant go

> "huh. I really should go check out
>   that site. Spend some time there...."

Really looking for "representative" type questions, to give other security pros a feel for the site, and make them interested in what we have to offer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about these 8:

- [3 failed password attempts](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/487/485)
- Forensic Toolbox questions [Q1](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36/485)
  and [Q2](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1149/485)
- [Biggest Unsolved Problems](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/698/485)
- Hardening server eg [Linux](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/993/485)
- [Securing home office](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1244/485)
- [IP Spoofing](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1009/485)
- [PCI](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1328/485)

Reasonably representative?

Comment: Thanks mate. Actually since it's OWASP I'm looking for mostly appsec-focused q's - and in IL they're a very pragmatic bunch, so the qs need to be purely practical, too. So the first and last are really good ones, the others - while interesting, AND representative - dont serve me here.

Comment: That said, I think the other qs would be great for anyone else in a similar situation, with the opportunity to show off the site to other security pros. (Thats why I asked it as a full question on Meta, and not just a chat...)

Comment: Ah - sorry I didn't get back on here until just now - probably too late for your meeting. Hope it goes well - have a good one. Will have to see if we can bring it up at the next OWASP Scotland meeting. @RoryMcCune - what do you reckon?

Comment: Thanks @Rory. Went over well - there was lots of interest there. Re questions, I just selected a semi-random smattering of high-voted questions, mostly from the appsec tag (or related topics). Also a couple of q's with lots of answers... Btw I'm leaving this q for the next person who is looking to speak about the site. Doesn't have to be much, its pretty straightforward - its mostly awareness + WIFM. I did 7 minutes...