# Sponsoring a community member to attend the 2011 Security BSides

Tags: discussion, conference

The 2011 Security BSides conferences are happening in a bunch of places all over the world:

http://www.securitybsides.com/w/page/12194156/FrontPage

**We would like to sponsor someone from the security.stackexchange.com community to attend this conference!**

(We're specifically looking at the one from **Feb 14 - Feb 15 in San Francisco**, but we are open to others as well.)

That means we will cover your airfare, hotel, and travel fees to make it to the conference, so long as you spend a little bit of time speaking / networking / blogging / sharing during your time there, and of course mention our fine, fine security community here. :)

So, the question part of the question:

- Does this make sense? What else should we be thinking of for the conference?
- Who would like to go?
- Who is willing and able to speak / network / blog / share at the conference?

Robert Cartaino, our community coordinator, will be following up.

Comment: Wow, fanTASTically cool idea, @Jeff! But just a q, why/how come you chose specifically that conference? It's not one of the "big 3" security confs, or even the big 5... (Not at all opposed to it, I've never been but it looks like a quality conf - just wondering...)

Comment: Hmm, I think I might answer my own meandering: is it the "community-driven", "encourages collaboration", and "discussions, demos, interaction and conversation" bits that did it? Makes it sound in line with SE/SOIS mission, too :)

Comment: Also that specific conf, RFP is closed already. So the sponsoree can network and mention, of course, but speaking is out.

Comment: BSides is a fantastic conference.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: @Bill - I agree, I heard good things about it. Wasn't knocking it, but as I said its not one of the "big" ones.

Comment: I responded to a tweet from @Jeff and recommended b-sides.  So far, b-sides is exactly what @AviD stated above (community, collaborative, etc.).  I’ve been to a few and I think  the value of getting involved with b-sides for this site could be awesome (especially given the # of b-sides events sprouting and the very low cost of entry).

Comment: I also think speaking at b-sides events may not be the best value for this site  – instead have members play more to the networking side.  For example, having members here be greeters at the b-sides door and handing out security.stackexchange.com stickers to every attendee would likely have greater reach (this implies security.stackexchange.com is willing to be a direct sponsor of b-sides).  This is just one idea – there are tons of more cool things to do.

Comment: What is the status of this proposal?

Comment: @neal it is complete! Rory attended and returned! Blog entry: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/community-conference-sponsorships/

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks for supporting the community like this!!   Nice link - worth putting in an update?  How about accepting his answer? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I for one would be happy to do it. I have talked for years at a range of events big and small on behalf of ISACA, the IISP, my team and others and really enjoy the networking side of things.

Things that work at conferences like this
 - small merchandise (T-shirts, lanyards etc) all help people to remember a week later
 - targeting talks which match the marketing aim (ie get networking before and after talks specifically relevant to security.stackexchange)
 - not sleeping (I'm thinking my seeming immunity to jet lag is useful here :-)

Just let me know.

---

Update - added a [question to see what thoughts you have on things to do to help publicise security.stackexchange.com](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/168/485).

Answer (score 5):

I second @Rory going for this. I think he'd do a great job, not to mention the English accent always goes over big in West Coast :)

That said, if for whatever reason it doesn't work out, I'd also consider doing this myself instead, I also have plenty of experience at lots of events - speaking at OWASP, RSA Conference, GRC, etc. Just today I [pushed the site](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/suggestions-for-best-questions) at the local OWASP chapter meeting... (oh, and I'm impervious to jet lag too - though I dont love flying).

I also happen to know some of the (potential) speakers there...

Comment: +1 - Lived in SF and agree about the British accent being a strong positive. Also, AviD would be good choice as well!

Answer (score 3):

Security BSides has an [April event in London,](http://bsideslondon.eventbrite.com/) which is closer to @Rory and for which the CFP hasn't closed yet, too.

Comment: yeah, but in London *I* would be the foreigner... ;)

Comment: Me too Avi - I'm Scottish :-)

Comment: My Scottish pal always takes offense when I call him "a Brit" ;)

Comment: @AviD - definitely a Brit, but the problem comes when you call Scots 'English' :-)

Comment: @Rory okay yeah, that's what I meant :$

Comment: @JeffAtwood - The London B-Sides is certainly closer to home, so less in the way of travel expenses - if that is an issue :-)

Comment: @Rory it was more the "and the CFP is still open" aspect... I'll be there anyway.

Comment: @GrahamLee - ahhhh. Gotcha. Off to check out the details now.