# OWASP Conference Sponsorship

Tags: discussion, feature-request, conference, site-promotion

In the spirit of [this post](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/site-promotion-suggestions), and several others on this site and on the SE blog, I'd like to see if SEI and ITsec can sponsor the upcoming [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) [regional conference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Israel_2011), in Israel (in September).

A while ago, I had proposed this in a Meta.SO post, but didn't get much response. It is quoted below as the original has since been deleted:

> From [OWASP.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page):
>
> > The Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) is a 501c3 not-for-profit worldwide charitable organization focused on improving the security of application software. Our mission is to make application security visible, so that people and organizations can make informed decisions about true application security risks.
>
> With all the good that SEI is doing, and sponsoring several open source projects to further their goal of making the Internet smarter, I think OWASP would be a great partner to that goal.
>
> Check the [membership page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Membership) for details.
> At the very least, sponsorship of local OWASP chapters / meetings should be a must.

Now, with the conference coming up, I'm even more invested here, as I am on the IL chapter board and responsible for the conference... :)

Specifically, [this conference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Israel_2011) (unlike most of the other AppSec conferences) is completely free to attend, and is totally covered by sponsorships. We are expecting several hundred to attend.

There are [several options for sponsoring](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Membership):

- Conference sponsor at several levels - Gold/Silver/etc (i.e. Chapter Sponsor)
- project sponsor for any OWASP project that SEI likes (like SO has done in the past for opensource projects...), such as [ESAPI](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API);
- OWASP member / Organization sponsor
- any mix of the above (can become full member, and designate part of the meembership fee to sponsor a specific chapter or project).

Specifically, my particular interest right now is [sponsorship for the conference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Israel_2011), as we are still looking to cover costs - it's important to us to keep this conference free. Otherwise, I'm happy for those unicornbucks to go to a great source of security info...

As noted, OWASP is a [501c3 not-for-profit](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Membership)....

Comment: ooh, and can we get some swag!

Comment: +1 for supporting OWASP

Answer (score 4):

At the recent AppSecEU conference in Dublin, which wasn't free, we still had sponsorship, to try and defray the cost of many hundred attendees, speakers expenses etc.

We had options such as sponsoring notebooks, rucksacks, pens, lunches etc. The company I was with sponsored the notepads and it was extraordinarily good value as everyone used the notepads, and the front page just had our logo and the OWASP logo so it would be seen everywhere.

AviD - if you speak to Eoin Keary in Dublin, he can probably give you a good run down on what worked best and maybe help to suggest what might be most useful for StackExchange.